# Virtual machine not starts because of no VT-x?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

Suddenly after my PC crash and repair I found that I can't start all VMWare virtual machines. I can't find any settings in my Asus motherboard B85M-E bios. In other hand hardware not changed since last crash.  How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I had that exact issue when VT-x was disabled in the BIOS; if you are sure it isn't, check the host registry settings; maybe Windows declares it as 'off' to running software because of such a setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is from a slightly different Asus motherboard, it should be very similar... In BIOS/EFI, go to Advanced then CPU Configuration menu, find the entry for Intel Virtualization Technology and enable it (note the scroll bars, they are tiny and easily missed), then press F10 to save and Reboot. You should no longer receive that error message and your guest machine should start normally. Most likely your BIOS was reset, I believe this is Disabled by default.

[image]